# Artifactory bower issue with marionette.js

Tags: jquery, marionette, bower, artifactory

There is a problem with bower-art for Artifactory Pro Power Pack 3.7.0(rev. 30185). I use the library marionette.js with dependencies on jquery and underscore which bower-art does not resolve. Original bower resolves this without any problems.

Executing:

```
bower-art install marionette
```

Output in console:

```
bower jquery#^1.8.0 || ^2.0.0          response No version found for ^1.8.0 || ^2.0.0. Available tags: [1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0a, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.3.1, 1.1.3a, 1.1.4, 1.1
.0, 1.10.0-beta1, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.11.0, 1.11.0-beta1, 1.11.0-beta2, 1.11.0-beta3, 1.11.0-rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.1-beta1, 1.11.1-rc1, 1.11.1-rc2, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.1a, 1.1b, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.2b,
1.2.2b2, 1.2.3, 1.2.3a, 1.2.3b, 1.2.4, 1.2.4a, 1.2.4b, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.3, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.1rc1, 1.3.2, 1.3b1, 1.3b2, 1.3rc1, 1.4, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.3rc1, 1.4.3rc2, 1.4.4, 1.4.4rc1,
1.4.4rc2, 1.4.4rc3, 1.4a1, 1.4a2, 1.4rc1, 1.5, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.1rc1, 1.5.2, 1.5.2rc1, 1.5b1, 1.5rc1, 1.6, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.1rc1, 1.6.2, 1.6.2rc1, 1.6.3, 1.6.3rc1, 1.6.4, 1.6.4rc1, 1.6b1, 1.6rc1
 1.7, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.1rc1, 1.7.2, 1.7.2b1, 1.7.2rc1, 1.7b1, 1.7b2, 1.7rc1, 1.7rc2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.3+1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.9.0, 1.9.0b1, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta3
 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.1.0, 2.1.0-beta1, 2.1.0-beta2, 2.1.0-beta3, 2.1.0-rc1, 2.1.1, 2.1.1-beta1, 2.1.1-rc1, 2.1.1-rc2, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4], Available branches: [1.11-stable, 2
1-stable, compat, master]
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an Artifactory bug with handling the `||` operator.
You can to follow the Jira issue created for this bug - [RTFACT-7544](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7544).